# Determine whether the following compound function is convex.

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

The function I wish to evaluate is:

$$
f(x)*t + \frac{g(x)}{t}
$$

where $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. $f(x)$ is a function of the variance with respect to the $n$-dimensional variable $x$:

$$
f(x)=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_{i}\cdot b_{i}-\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^n x_{j }\cdot b_{j})^2}{n}
$$
where $b_i\geq 0$.

$g(x)$ is a linear function of $x$: $g(x) = \sum\limits_{i\in \mathcal{I}}(1-a_{i})*x_{i}, a_{i}\leq 1$. The variable $t\in \mathbb{R}^+$.

How can the convexity or concavity of this function be determined?
I am able to prove that the variance function and the function $g(x)$ are convex. I have studied some basics of convex optimization, understand the definitions of convex sets, convex functions, etc., but I cannot judge the convexity of the above function. I hope to be able to prove that the above function is convex to solve it using cvxpy. Or is there a way to transform the above function into a more solvable form?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The form of your problem kind of reminded me about the "perspective" operator, which is a convex-preserving operator, but much less known than the other convex-preserving operations. With this, we can see that by g's linearity, we have that :
$$\frac{g(x)}{t} = g\bigg(\frac{x}{t}\bigg) = g(P(x,t))$$

where P(.,.) is the perspective operator, and by the sets in which x and t are defined, then g(x)/t is convex with respect to (x,t). Then, it is left to show that $f(x)\cdot t$ is convex, but currently I don't know if it goes from here. At least by my knowledge, product of convex functions need not to be convex...

Look up "convex-preserving operations" for a more detailed survey of the perspective function :)

Comment: Note that the sum of convex functions is convex, so you can focus on $f(x)\cdot t$, and probably directly examine its hessian if required. We can't really do that without knowing the precise form of $f$ though.

Comment: Thank you! I understand your point. Now, we just need to determine if the function \( f(x) \) is a convex function. Here, \( f(x) \) represents the variance with respect to the vector \( x \), which is given by:

$$
f(x)=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_{i}\cdot b_{i}-\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^n x_{j }\cdot b_{j})^2}{n}
$$

where the constant \( b_i \geq 0 \). For such a special form of function, is it only possible to determine using the Hessian matrix? For an \( n \)-dimensional vector, I feel that calculating the Hessian matrix might be a bit complex.

Comment: I thought you already said (f(x)) was convex. Anyways, it is trivial to see that, for the form you gave it, it is convex: you have a summation of the square of a linear function of x. I mean, everything inside the square is a linear function of x, and squaring is convex. Then you end up summing convex functions, son f(x) is indeed convex.

For more details, you can recall compositions of real-valued and convex functions, which states this is the case (particularlly, because squaring is non-decreasing). 

Still, the problem is to see if $(f(x)\cdot t)$ is convex.